# Vertex Displacement Doesn't Work in Three.js

Tags: opengl-es, three.js, webgl, glsl

I've spent the last week experimenting with Three.js and WebRTC and feel like I've exhausted documentation on this subject. I'm trying to map `uniform sampler2D tDiffuse;` to this vertex shader.  The brightness of each pixel in tDiffuse should map to a vertex displacement on each vertex of the output. But I get the following error: `ERROR: 0:80: 'constructor' : not enough data provided for construction`

Right now, this shader is in the effects pipeline after the model is rendered. Do I need to specify width and height or am I missing something? Is there something wrong with my code, which I've cobbled together from a few different sources? Can I even do vertex displacement n this effects pipeline or do I need to apply the shader differently, to the mesh in my scene? I understand the theory behind what I need to do, but GLSL and furthermore this three.js pipeline is new to me, although I have lots of experience with similar graphical applications.

```
THREE.RuttEtraShader = {

    uniforms: {

        "tDiffuse": { type: "t", value: null },
        "opacity":  { type: "f", value: 1.0 }
    },



    vertexShader: [

    'uniform sampler2D tDiffuse;',
    'varying vec3 vColor;',
    "varying vec2 vUv;",

    'void main() {',
        'vec4 newVertexPos;',
        'vec4 dv;',
        'float df;',
        "vUv = uv;",
        'dv = texture2D( tDiffuse, vUv.xy );',
        'df = 0.30*dv.x + 0.59*dv.y + 0.11*dv.z;',
        'newVertexPos = vec4( normalize( position ) * df * 10.0 ) + vec4( position, 1.0 );', 
        'vColor = vec3( dv.x, dv.y, dv.z );',

        'gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * newVertexPos;',
    '}'

    ].join("\n"),

    fragmentShader: [

        "uniform float opacity;",

        "uniform sampler2D tDiffuse;",

        "varying vec2 vUv;",

        "void main() {",

            "vec4 texel = texture2D( tDiffuse, vUv );",
            "gl_FragColor = opacity * texel;",

        "}"




    ].join("\n")

};
```

Comment: Changed line 'newVertexPos = vec4( normalize( position ) * df * 10.0 ) + vec4( position, 1.0 );',' to ''newVertexPos = vec4( normalize( position ) * df * 10.0, 1.0 ) + vec4( position, 1.0 );',' and no more error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Effectively, your GLSL compiler is brain-dead.

It is having trouble with the line: `normalize (position) ...` because you have not declared position. Instead of giving you a useful message that explains this, instead it complains that `position` does not have proper dimensions.

This of course assumes you have actually pasted the proper vertex / fragment shaders. I am not convinced, as neither one of those shaders has 80 lines of code.

Comment: Would this be correct then? 'position = vUv.xy' I thought position was a default variable used by Three.js. I've seen it used in many examples without being explicitly declared.

Comment: You are right, Three.js uses `position` as a reserved word (`vec3` in fact). *Tsk tsk*, libraries should prefix reserved words for clarity sake (e.g. `gl_` for OpenGL and `tjs_` for Three.js). The result of normalizing (position) gets you a 3 component vector and you are trying to use that to construct a 4 component vector. Depending on the desired results you may be able to replace `vec4( normalize( position ) * df * 10.0 )` with `vec4( normalize( position ) * df * 10.0, 1.0 )`... the proper value for the 4th component is unknown to me -- it should probably be either 0.0 or 1.0.

Comment: Awesome, that cleared up the error and thanks for the explanation. I agree, the documentation has a long way to go. Now when I put the vertex shader in the effects chain ('composer.addPass( effectRuttEtra)') it makes the entire scene go dark, no more mesh. I have a very simple scene set up with a mesh being textured by a video and the shaders running through an effects chain like in the examples. I remove the pass and its fine, I get my mesh back. Any ideas?

Comment: I think I may have explained the `newVertexPos` solution incorrectly. If you add vec4 (..., 1.0) to vec4 (..., 1.0) you wind up with vec4 (..., 2.0). The W component is used for perspective division. It is possible that what is really happening here has to do with the post-perspective depth values, they are closer than they should be. Have you tried to see if using `vec4( normalize( position ) * df * 10.0, 0.0 )` produces different results?

Comment: Yes, I tried both 'vec4( normalize( position ) * df * 10.0, 0.0 )' and 'vec4( normalize( position ) * df * 10.0, 1.0 )' and same result.

Comment: Do I have to specify depth testing or overdraw for the composer or renderer?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have never worked with Three.js before, but I would imagine for displacement you really want a depth buffer and depth testing.